# Is it possbile to mount Windows filesystems without using the root account?

Tags: linux, mount, non-root-user

As we all know, the intervention of root is necessary to mount a filesystem on Linux. But is it possible to do this without access to the root account? Because I don't know the password of root.

Comment: What linux distro are you on? Does the `sudo` command exist?

Comment: @ Random - Fedora,and sudo command is exist.But I don't want to use root access to do this.Any way can do that but root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is something of an oxymoron - you start by stating that root is required to mount filesystems then ask how filesystems can be mounted without root access.

Yes, it's completely possible - and because this is a Unix type system there's lots of different ways to do it. You could use sudo to allow the user to run a specific script as root which will mount the filesystem, or use [pam_mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/pam_mount.8.html), or add the filesystem to the fstab with appropriate options to mount [as a non-root user](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Writing_to_FAT32_as_Normal_User) with the `user` option, or to mount the filesystem [automaticaly on boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Systemwide_Mounts) (as root) with the `auto` option

Comment: @ symcbean - Your answer seems also need root competence to config Unix type system. But now I have only a ordinary user account,so I can't config Unix system. What can I do?By the way, Unix system is server here.

Comment: @binghenzq: they don't require the root password *at the time of mounting*. If you don't have root acces on the machine it's still possible to access an SMB filesystem (using smbclient) but it's not possible to mount *any* filesystem. If nobody knows the root password then your system is highly vulnerable and this MUST be resolved.

Comment: @ symcbean - SMB is a good idea,I just want to share files between windows and Unix.I will have a try,thanks.

Comment: SMB/CIFS is definitely the way to go for that (or if you're able to get onto the windows machine, something like winsshfs or winscp if ssh is available on the linux server)

Comment: @symcbean It's possible that he has a linux distribution that doesn't allow direct login with root but requires sudo.