# Mount a windows share without having root credentials

Tags: linux, mount, samba, non-root-user

I am trying to mount a Windows shared folder in my home folder.  I am able to execute the following command from a Linux (i.e., CentOS) machine which I have sudo access.  The command that I am using is:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //172.17.53.171/Projects ~/RemoteProjects -o username=domain/mhicks
```

The real trick is trying to mount the same folder on a machine which I don't have sudo/root access.  In order to use the mount command it is stating that I need root access.  How can I mount/map a Window's shared folder in Linux without sudo/root access?

Perhaps mount is the wrong way of going about it?

Comment: partial answer here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102507/is-it-possbile-to-mount-windows-filesystems-without-using-the-root-account?rq=1

Comment: FUSE is an answer. check this out - http://askubuntu.com/questions/24348/how-do-i-mount-samba-share-as-non-root-user

Comment: consider `smbclient` - https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [Mounting Windows shares in Linux userspace](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2010/mounting-windows-shares-in-linux-userspace/). You'll still initially require root access to get it setup.